# Listview with onclick event problem

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

Hi all I would like to create  a listview in android with items populated from the database. On clicking each item, as in the message inbox, where opening a message will redirected to anther page with complete message, another intent should be started... How could we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-2
onItemClick, call another activity.

Answer (score 1):

See [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html). Google will give you plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new man of Android developer,it's my pleasure to communicate with you. ^_^

1. First you should call setListAdapter() to see up a adapter for your Listview
2. Then you must set the listener for the Items of your list:setOnItemClickListener()

More: see the sample from Android developers Guide:Resources->Tutorials->Hello, Views ->ListView

Hope that my answer can help you.